# Wordpress Woocommerce Product Search only working when logged into admin

Tags: wordpress, search, admin, woocommerce, product

Having a really weird issue I have never ran into before and don't see anyone else having a similar issue so I thought I would make a question for it, the issue is on this particular wordpress site: http://bynubar.com/

The problem is, users cannot search using the regular wordpress/woocommerce product search

http://bynubar.com/?s=art&post_type=product

they get "NO PRODUCTS FOUND WHICH MATCH YOUR SELECTION"

However, if you log into the wp-admin of wordpress and do the same thing, it works just fine! So this issue only affects users that aren't logged in, which is unfortunately pretty much everyone :(

Where should I look to resolve this issue that seems to make the products unsearchable unless you are logged in?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this, the database was apparently corrupted somehow in some obscure place and I had to use WP_ALLOW_REPAIR

Automatic Database Optimizing
Added with Version 2.9, there is automatic database optimization support, which you can enable by adding the following define to your wp-config.php file only when the feature is required

define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );
The script can be found at {$your_site}/wp-admin/maint/repair.php

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php